# Visual Studio 2012 xaml Designer System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: wpf

Everytime I try to load a WPF window/page/userControl, the xaml designer crashes and System.BadImageFormatException is thrown. I've tried to switch the platform to X86 in configuration manager but it does not work. The following is the complete detail of exception:

**System.BadImageFormatException**

> [C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll] The signature is incorrect.
>      at Microsoft.Expression.Markup.XmlCharType..cctor()
>
> System.TypeInitializationException
>   The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Expression.Markup.XmlCharType' threw an exception.

Any idea guys?, thank you!

Comment: Maybe you are trying to insert URI instead of image? If you cannot localize exception, try to comment content of usercontrol that throwing exception.. If it will not be thrown after this, you should comment part of content until you'll find incorrect area. When exception is localized, provide incorrect xaml here, it may help to determine the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue by Windows Task Manager and ending the process 'Microsoft Visual Studio XAML UI Designer'. In fact some issues are solved by stopping this process. Visual Studio automatically run this a new fresh instance of this process.